# PHP 5.5 "Undefined variable" Notice inconsistency

Tags: php, php-5.5

In the code below we can see 5 examples of using undefined variable.
With error reporting and displaying being on, we should see 5 notices.
However, in php 5.5 we will see only 3 of them ($b, $d, $e) when using "http interpreter" [eg. via apache mod] or fpm directly but all 5 of them if running from cli.

Why is that? Does anybody know anything about this inconsistency?

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$b==1;
if($c);
if ($d==1);
(int) $e;
(boolean) $f;
```

Below is example dump, from a friend of mine

```
$ cat v.php 
<?php
$a;
$b==1;
if($c);
if ($d==1);
(int) $e;
(boolean) $f;

$ cat v.sh
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_FILENAME=`pwd`/v.php \
REQUEST_METHOD=GET \
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php5-fpm.sock 

$ php v.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: b in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 3
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: c in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 4
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: d in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 5
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: e in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 6
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: f in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 7

$ ./v.sh 
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: b in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 3
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: d in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 5
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: e in /tmp/fpm-test/v.php on line 6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
Content-type: text/html
```

Comment: Looking at a [whole range of PHP versions](http://3v4l.org/TLWvD), I don't see that difference in 5.5.9

Comment: @MarkBaker I think you misunderstood question. Question is why there are 5 notice when running script from CLI and only 3 when running by server.